KDE lockscreen doesn't accept a correct password
I have installed kde-desktop on my Ubuntu 22.04.
When I login to the KDE session and hit ctrl+L to lock the screen, the kscreenlocker app doesn't allow me to unlock it back.
I can see that the password is correct (there is a preview password button), but it says "Unlocking failed". So I have to click on "switch user", and login using GDM. After that it unlocks my session.
How can I figure out what is wrong?

My wife's machine was set to autologin, and ran into this problem. I solved it by updating her password from root.
In her case, Alt+Ctrl+F3 got me a terminal, where I logged into root. I ran the password utility and updated her password to the same one she already had and rebooted.
passwd herusername and problem solved.
